# Distribute TextViews in LinearLayout based on content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

As described in the title, I am trying to have 2 TextViews next to eachother in a LinearLayout. Both of the textviews for example contain 10 words each. In that case, I want them to be 50% in width. However, when the first TextView has 10 words, and the other one has 1 word, I would like the first TextView to be wider (~ like 90% or so). How can I do so?

Note: I did try to search, but the only things I found was how to resize **the font** in a TextView.

I've added a bit of visual of how the TextViews look (don't mind the Android Studio random hover borders).

[image]

Also my current code, in case you want to help:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="My title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_other_title"
        android:text="My other title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note: I would prefer to use only xml for it, but if it is only possible programatically, then that will do**

Comment: If you say you want to change weight of the TextView depending how many words are in it you have to do it dynamically in code using conditions. XML can only do it in static way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so, you'll have to calculate the estimate weight of both of the TextViews, using the length of the text. The length of the *the other title* will be used as weight for the *title*, and the length of the *title* will be used for the weight of *the other title*.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams titleParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
titleParams.weight = myOtherTitle.getText().length();

LinearLayout.LayoutParams myOtherTitleParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myOtherTitleParams.weight = title.getText().length();

title.setLayoutParams(titleParams);
myOtherTitle.setLayoutParams(myOtherTitleParams);
```